# Issue with random distribution for my Fisher-Yates shuffle implementation?

Tags: python

I was trying to learn the Fisher-Yates shuffle this week, and I was wondering if there's a good way to implement uniform random distribution without using python build in shuffle function.

https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

I tried to solve it naive shuffle way, but it gets tricky when you have to implement a uniform random distribution.

Here's some sample code that I have build.

```
# I'll implement the shuffle in place algorithm then test it # to make sure it fits the statistical definition of a uniform random
# shuffle

import random


def get_random(floor, ceiling):
    """return a random number in the closed interval (floor, ceiling)"""
    return random.randint(floor, ceiling)  # randint does this already


# this is non-uniform naive shuffle
# stripped of comments, it differs from the in_place_uniform_shuffle
# by 1 character. (A critical 1 character difference!)

# using statistics in the unit tests, it can be seen that the naive
# shuffle never converges on a uniform shuffling, empirically, the
# variance can at times be seen to increase even with increasing
# repetitions.


def naive_shuffle(the_list):

    # for each index in the list
    for first_index in xrange(0, len(the_list) - 1):

        # grab a random other index
        second_index = get_random(first_index, len(the_list) - 1)

        # and swap the values
        if second_index != first_index:
            the_list[first_index], the_list[second_index] = \
                the_list[second_index], the_list[first_index]
```

https://repl.it/LrSA/3

I appreciate any feedback

Comment: True random distribution shuffles are problematic because any implementation of a random number selector will never be truly random. Fisher-Yates can be affected by this by 1) the number of elements to be shuffled, and 2) the internal bit state of the pseudorandom generator. If the bit state is not as large as all possibilities, the distribution will never be uniform since some permutations can never be achieved. This is a well-known problem in CS.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking about.  In the linked code, `naive_shuffle` and `in_place_uniform_shuffle` are algorithmically identical (the former just skips swapping when `second_index` and `first_index` are the same).  The statistics I see from both are essentially the same, and also essentially the same as I see from Python's `random.shuffle`.

Comment: @TimPeters: heads-up: I think you have been misquoted 12 years ago: [What is the actual impact of calling socket.recv with a bufsize that is not a power of 2?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46538886), and people are confused now. ;-)

Comment: @DavidJenkins Good point, however, the standard Mersenne Twister used by default in Python's `random` module has a period of `2^19937-1`, so it _should_ be able to produce all the permutations for lists of length < 2080 (2080! < 2^19937-1 < 2081!). Of course, it's a Good Idea to seed the PRNG with plenty of entropy if you intend to generate lots of permutations with it. ;)

Comment: FWIW, `random.randint` (and the related `random` module functions) normally give uniform results (assuming the range is under 2^19937-1), since they work by generating a random string of bits of sufficient length and then looping if the number thus generated is too big. Please see the source for details.